# Using a Javascript function to add a background image on-top of a background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` that is used for a piece in a game of checkers:

```
<div class="blackCoin" ondblclick="makeKing(this)">
```

When, for example double clicked, I want to make the piece a king by adding [a crown](http://images.clipartpanda.com/black-crown-clipart-crown-md.png) on top of the existing background color:

```
function makeKing(obj){
            obj.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://images.clipartpanda.com/black-crown-clipart-crown-md.png')";
 }
```

Here is the full [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/etd6mfx1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works fine with your code, the only thing you need to do is add `background-size: contain;` to the `.blackCoin` class and it will work.